# How to hide / stop server version in HTTP/1.1 200 OK in rails [ nginx/1.0.6 + Phusion Passenger 3.0.9 ]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, passenger

Hi in my rails application I am using nginx/1.0.6 , Phusion Passenger to host my rails application.
But for the security issue I want to stop the display of headers on public network.
Now when I run the following curl command.
`

> curl -I http://domain.name

it give me the following trace:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) 3.0.9
ETag: "b7da2b7b2fa6349"
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
X-Runtime: 1.193656
Set-Cookie: demand_session=BAh7ByIQX2NzcmZfdG9rZW4iMUVMREdHRDJGcHhnVzhWNTNsRGhGSWRyNmRQbWZZSnpyZGcwbFYx3D%3D--eb470df0951aac0e6612861ef30ed7a699d073a0; path=/; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Server: nginx/1.0.6 + Phusion Passenger 3.0.9 (mod_rails/mod_rack)
```

But I want to hide these headers: Server,Set-Cookie,X-Powered-By,X-UA-Compatible,ETag,Cache-ControlCache-Control to be display.

Comment: I can understand wanting to hide `X-Powered-By` and maybe `Server`, but you'll probably find your apps crippled to the point of uselessness and/or very inefficient if you shut off cookies and cache control, and there's really no good reason to do that anyway.  Unfortunately I don't have an actual answer to your question.

Comment: The main thing which I want to hide is server version's because precise software versions might aid an attacker in mounting tailored attacks on the server.

Comment: Yeah, it's a legitimate concern, especially after the recent Rails problems.  I don't know that it's worth it or will actually help, but I appreciate the attempt. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using proxy you can use and configure directive `proxy_hide_header` from `proxy` module by that:

```
proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;
proxy_hide_header X-UA-Compatible;
proxy_hide_header X-Runtime;
proxy_hide_header ETag;

# and so on...
```

But this directive allow you only to hide headers coming from proxy server. For response headers coming from main server not proxy you can use directive `set` and variable `$sent_http_HEADER` where `HEADER` means header name you would like to set. Here an example:

```
set $sent_http_x_powered_by your_value;
set $sent_http_etag your_value;
set $sent_http_cache_control your_value;

# and so on...
```

But take in consideration two things:
1. `Set` directive works only in `server`,`location` and `if` blocks,
2. As you can read in comments to your question it's not realy good idea to hide or change some headers like Cache-Control because they aren't only information but have impact on browser and user clients work.

Comment: can you please tell me where I can set these values.

Comment: I think in `server` block and then it will work for all `location` blocks or in some `location` blocks where you need those directives

Answer (score 3):

Use [passenger_show_version_in_header off](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_passenger_show_version_in_header_lt_on_off_gt) and [server_tokens off](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_tokens).

Comment: passenger_show_version_in_header will remove the passenger version but not passenger it self, regrettably.